# What is the location of background image set from Safari?

Tags: safari, desktop, macos

Safari allows you to set any image as desktop background right from the browser.

[image: Use Image as Desktop Picture in Safari]

**Desktop & Screen Saver** preference pane will then display it as *Safari Desktop Picture*.

[image: Safari Desktop Picture]

No filename, no location, and if I change it, seems like the picture is lost.
I find it frustrating because, although I frequently change wallpapers, I'd like to keep each of them.
I could as well download the file manually but isn't this what **Use As Desktop Picture** exists for?

So, the question is:

> **Where is this image actually stored on my hard drive?**
>   How do I retrieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open **~/Library/Safari/**.
It is there, called **Safari Desktop Picture.jpg** (or whatever the extension is).

[image: Safari Desktop Picture location]

If you're on Lion, to get to **Library** folder you may open **Finder**, select **Go** from the top menu and  hold <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>. The normally hidden **Library** menu will reveal itself in the folder list. Open it, and proceed to **Safari** subfolder.

If you're not on Lion or just prefer the quick way, open **Finder**, press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to open directory prompt and paste **~/Library/Safari/**:

[image: Safari Desktop Picture location]

Comment: Using the Go To Folder keyboard shortcut on Lion will still work if you type out ~/Library - I think it will tab-complete as expected.  No need to specifically use the Go menu plus option key modifier as per above.

Comment: I think it is slightly more fun, that's why I included it.

Comment: @da4: Thanks for the comment though. I made an edit.

Comment: I'm running macOS Catalina (10.15.3) and found the image in a slightly different location. Replace the _Safari_ folder with _Safari Shared Data_. The full path is `~/Library/Safari Shared Data/Safari Desktop Picture.jpg`